# How do I use the user zoom of a plotly time series plot to print the value counts of a column in a table based on that time period?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to make a three plot dash app that does three things, first it show a map with various point that can be clicked. doing so will plot a time series of data related with that point. I've got it working up to this point. The next interactive feature I want to add is to make a table of the value counts of a column based on the time period that a user selects by zooming the 2 plot. So basically take the user selected xaxis range to make a value counts table.

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll'
    }
}

fig_map = px.scatter_mapbox(df, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name="community_name", 
                           hover_data={'community_name':True, 'lat':False, 'lon':False}, zoom=3, height=800,
                           color_discrete_sequence=["fuchsia"], mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig_map.update_layout(clickmode='event+select')

app.layout =   html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='map', figure=fig_map , className='six columns'),
      
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(
                    id='time_series1',
                    style={'height': 400}
                ),
]),
    html.Table(
        id='my-table'
        #columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    #    data=pd.DataFrame({'Value': top_10_species.index, 'Frequency': top_10_species.values})
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('time_series1', 'figure'),
    Input('map', 'selectedData'))
def display_selected_data(selectedData):
    clicked_community = selectedData['points'][0]['customdata'][0]
    dff = df[df['community_name'] == clicked_community]
    dff['date_offset'] = dff['date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
    dfg1 = dff.groupby('date')['weight_kg'].sum()
    dfg2 = dff.groupby('date_offset')['total_price_usd'].sum()
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=dfg1.index, y=dfg1, name="weight_kg"), secondary_y=False)
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=dfg2.index, y=dfg2, name="Price_USD"), secondary_y=True)
    #fig = px.line(data_frame=dff, x='date', y='weight_kg', color='community_name')
    #fig.update_traces(mode='lines+markers')
    return fig


# Create callback function
@app.callback(
    Output('my-table', 'data'),
    Input('time_series1', 'relayoutData')
)
def update_value_counts(relayoutData):
        # Get x-axis range from relayoutData
    x_range = relayoutData['time.range']
    
    clicked_community = selectedData['points'][0]['customdata'][0]
    dff = df[(df['community_name'] == clicked_community) &
                     (df['time'] >= x_range[0]) & (df['time'] <= x_range[1])]
        # Get value counts for the column of interest
    value_counts = filtered_df['column_of_interest'].value_counts()

    # Convert value counts to a list of dictionaries
    data = [{'column_of_interest': k, 'count': v} for k, v in value_counts.items()]

    return data
```

I've tried the above code, but it doesn't like the time.range I'm not sure if thats because it is a date time of not. I know that I have to make a new callback, but I am having trouble getting the appropriate data time object to use for the value counts. Can anyone help me figure out this problem?